# kubectl delete pod vs click delete button on GKE web ui

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

we have pods on [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine).

we can delete pod by `kubectl -n <ns> delete pod <pod name>`.
we can also delete the pod by clicking the following delete button.

[image]

what are the differences?
what are the results if I did both?

thanks

**UPDATE**

thanks. The pod has `terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60`. what will happen if I run `kubectl delete pod pod_name` and then `ctrl C`? Then click the delete button on the web ui? all these are in 60 seconds.

I am curious whether it will delete the pod by force without waiting for 60 seconds.

thanks

```
$ kubectl -n ns delete pod pod-0
pod "pod-0" deleted
^C
```

Comment: You could look on what is the `State` of your pod is by running `$ kubectl get pods -o wide --watch`. The pod will enter into `Terminating` state and running `CTRL+C` after it went into `Terminating` state won't stop this process. There will be no additional effect running it in `GKE` UI afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Both trigger the same API call to the kube-apiserver. If you try to delete something twice, the second call will fail either "already deleted" or "not found".

Comment: thanks. what will happen if I run `kubectl delete pod pod_name` and then `ctrl C`?

```
$ kubectl -n ns delete pod pod-0
pod "pod-0" deleted
^C

```

Comment: It’s a single api call so if the request made it to the server then it will be deleted. If you abort it before the request is sent, then it won’t be.

Answer (score 0):

Well as @codegenerator answered is correct.

About your updated question answer is

> The Pod will stays in a Terminating state and is killed after terminationGracePeriodSeconds of pod ends.